# Reset the value of the 1st component of UIPickerView when component 0 is changed

Tags: arrays, swift, uipickerview

I can't figure out how to reset to component 0 the array used in the first component of the PickerView, when component 0 is changed (in order to avoid possible errors due to indexOutOfRange).

This is the structure of my data

```
let bananas = ["banana1", "banana2"]
let fruitArray = ["banana1" : ["cherry1","cherry2"], "banana2" : ["cherry1", "cherry2", "cherry3"]]


func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 2
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    if component == 0 {
        return bananas.count
    }
    else {
        let selectedBanana = pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)
        return fruitArray[banana[selectedBanana]]!.count
    }
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {


    let selectedBanana = pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)
    let selectedCherry = pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 1)


    bananaPicked = bananas[selectedBanana]
    cherryPicked = fruitArray[bananaPicked]![selectedCherry]


    pickerView.reloadAllComponents() 
    }


func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
if component == 0 {
    return bananas[row]
}
else {
    let selectedBanana = pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)
    return fruitArray[selectedBanana]![row]
}
}
```

Right now when I'm (let's say) in banana2 and cherry3, but I switch to banana1, I get an indexOutOfRange error, because of course the first banana array does not have a third item. My wish it whenever the banana row is changed to reset to 0 the cherry row.

__________ UPDATE ______________
This is another error cause the crashing that I found (indexOutOfRange), I posted a screenshot.

[image: Image causing Crash]

Comment: `pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)` returns **Int** value. 
But your `fruitArray` is a **Dictionary**

Comment: Which line is causing the error?

Comment: @AhmetSinaUstem With the lines afterwards I should be using that Int to access an item at a precise location in the list (coming as value from the dictionary, using the key banana)

Comment: @rmaddy the line causing the error is cherryPicked = fruitArray[bananaPicked]![selectedCherry], before reloadAllComponents(). And the error is index out of range

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the selected row to 0 in component 1 when component 0 is changed.

Also, there is no need to reload all of the components.  Only component 1 needs reloading.

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

    if component == 0 {
        pickerView.selectRow(0, inComponent: 1, animated: false)
    }

    let selectedBanana = pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)
    let selectedCherry = pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 1)

    bananaPicked = bananas[selectedBanana]
    cherryPicked = fruitArray[bananaPicked]![selectedCherry]

    //pickerView.reloadAllComponents()
    pickerView.reloadComponent(1)
}
```

For your second crash, try some defensive programming to avoid the crash:

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    if component == 0 {
        return bananas[row]
    }
    else {
        let selectedBanana = pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)
        let rowData = fruitArray[bananas[selectedBanana]]!
        if rowData.indices.contains(row) {
            return rowData[row]
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. That fixed it. As I was just testing the app right now though, I encountered another problem that made it crash. I've just tried randomly scrolling the component 0 of the picker and at the same time the component 1. It has suddenly crashed. Do you think there are any other ways to fix it besides limiting the possible touches in the screen to one? Thanks

Comment: Again, it's an index out of range in line return fruitArray[selectedBanana]![row] inside titleForRow. I observed that it happened when the component 0 was selecting above the first row, and the component1 was scrolling down.

Comment: Is it because the index for component 0 is -1?

Comment: I've just checked the value and it happened when (equivalently in this case), selectedBanana = 0 and row = 2 in this following line: return fruitArray[selectedBanana]![row] . Might be still because of the same error as before, but if I do it too quickly and simultaneously it doesn't have the time to reset to 0.

Comment: See the updated answer for a solution to your second crash.